# Why no bounded wildcard in input parameters of synchronizedCollection() static factory method?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I was going through the Java tutorial and stumbled on something which I did not understand. In the Collections trail, they talk about [Wrapper implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html), there I notice two static factory methods -

```
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c);

public static <T> Collection<T> unmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends T> c);
```

I am wondering why does synchronized wrappers don't use bounded wildcards? i. e. Why is the signature of synchronizedCollection not the following?

```
public static <T> Collection<T> synchronizedCollection(Collection<? extends T> c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection<? extends T> c` with that you can only get stuffs but cannot add to it, which makes sense in case of `unmodifiableCollection`, for the method the argument should only act as producer. But in case of `synchronizedCollection`, it's synchronized but still modifialbe, it should also be able to add and remove, so it has to be `Collection<T> c`, it should act as both producer and consumer.

This might be helpful to know about [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/738746)

Answer (score -1):

I think `unmodifiableCollection` is in the wrong. Both methods intend to wrap `Collection<T>` as `Collection<T>`, there's no reason to change the type argument.

Sure it is more flexible to take in a `Collection<? extends T>`, so caller can request to convert a `Collection<Integer>` to an unmodifiable `Collection<Integer>` or `Collection<Number>` or `Collection<Object>` etc. But who needs that? A readonly `Collection<Integer>` is in every way better than `Collection<Number>` anyway.

If the input type itself contains wildcard, e.g.

```
Collection<? extends Number> someNumbers = ...;
```

with `unmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends T>)` we can do

```
          Collection<Number> readonlyNumbers 
                             = unmodifiableCollection(someNumbers);
          Collection<Object> readonlyObjects 
                             = unmodifiableCollection(someNumbers);
```

but with `unmodifiableCollection2(Collection<T>)` we must

```
Collection<? extends Number> readonlyNumbers 
                             = unmodifiableCollection2(someNumbers);
Collection<? extends Object> readonlyObjects  
                             = unmodifiableCollection2(someNumbers);
```

the 2nd version is messier, but it is probably more politically correct.